# Solr extract to upload documents not working using Solr 8.10.1

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

We have an existing application that currently uses Solr 3.6.1 for indexing and searching of documents. Using Solr 3.6.1,everything works fine.

I built a Solr 8.10.1 server and when I try to upload documents to a Solr collection in 8.10.1, I get a "Data is invalid at root level" error. Any help with would be appreciated.
Thanks

CODE:

```
ISolrOperations<GetPHP> solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<GetPHP>>();
                                            var response =
                                                    solr.Extract(
                                                    new ExtractParameters(file, nextDocFile)
                                                    {
                                                        ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                                                        ExtractOnly = false,
                                                        AutoCommit = true
                                                    });
```

ERROR LOG:

```
Exception Type: XmlException Error in: http://localhost:63408/document/new_document.aspx?uID=2081&dType=PHP&txtPath=%2fContribution+Folders%2fPHP%2f00+-++CLOSED+FILES%2f01-Intelligence%2f01-Personnel Error Message: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Error Source: System.Xml
StackTrace:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseExtract(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Extract(ExtractParameters parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Extract(ExtractParameters parameters)
   at xyz_app.Document.new_document.Upload_File() in
```

Comment: The code if from an ASP.NET C# application. My research says Solr 8.x returns JSON while my code is looking for XML. I don't know how  to code a parameter in the Solr extract function. It may be something else causing the problem too,

Answer (score 0):

Solr switched to JSON as the default response writer in version 7.0.  Before that it was XML.

My application was expecting XML, but was receiving a JSON respnse from Solr

SOLUTION:

I made the following update to conf/solrconfig.xml in each of my Solr cores.

CHANGE line below

```
<queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
```

TO

```
<queryResponseWriter name="xml"
    default="true"
  class="solr.XMLResponseWriter" />
```

This causes SOLR to return XML instead of JSON